# JFrame background color is not changing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, background-color

I'm trying to change the color of my JFrame but for some reason it isn't changing and remains the default grey color? This is my code it's included before I've added all my panels and elements:

```
private static void guiApp()
{
    
    
    //frame 2
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame2.setLocation(100,50);
    frame2.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Could this be because I've added other panels to the frame? I've tried changing the colors of those with panel.setBackground(Color.red) but no color seems to be appearing so I am confused if I've missed a step or included the code in the wrong spot.

Comment: `frame2.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);` or `frame2.getLayeredPane().setBackground(Color.red);` ? for more details see [JRootPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JRootPane.html)

Comment: *I've tried changing the colors of those with panel.setBackground(Color.red) but no color seems to be appearing * - post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. We can't compile and test the code you posted. The code doesn't even show how you add a panel to the frame.

Answer (score 3):

The "content pane" of the frame is a JPanel which covers the entire frame. So you need to change the background of the content pane.

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.RED ):
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to better understand the structure of a frame.

> Could this be because I've added other panels to the frame?

Yes, panels are opaque by default so they will paint on top of the content pane. You could make these panels non-opaque:

```
panel.setOpaque( false );
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now your child panel is transparent so the background of the content pane will show.

Or if you leave the panel opaque (which is is by default) and do:

```
panel.setBackground( Color.BLUE);
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then the "blue" panel will cover the "red" content pane.